# Existence of linear injection $T:S^2 V\rightarrow \Lambda^2 V$

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Let $\dim_\Bbb{F}V>2$. I want to know if there is $T:S^2V\rightarrow  \Lambda^2 V$ such that $T$ is linear and injective.

In the finite case, if $\dim_\Bbb{F} V=n<\infty$, such $T$ cannot exist. Indeed,

$$\dim\Lambda^2V=\begin{pmatrix}n \\ 2\end{pmatrix}< \begin{pmatrix}n+1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}=\dim S^2 V. $$

But what can I say in the infinite case? Seems like the dimensions of $\Lambda^2V$ and $S^2V$ could be equal.

I know that, if $(v_i)_{i\in I}$ is a basis for $V$, and $<$ a total order relation in $I$, so the set

$$\{v_{i_1}\wedge v_{i_2}:i_1 < i_2\} $$

is a basis for $\Lambda^2 V$, and the set

$$\{v_{i_1}\odot v_{i_2}:i_1\leq i_2\} $$

is a basis for $S^2 V.$

Can I use the fact that $\dim V=\infty$ to construct a linear injection between these basis?

Comment: In the infinite dimensional case $V$, $\bigwedge^k V$ and $S^kV$ all have the same dimension, for any $k\ge2$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng How can I construct an explicit injection (or even a bijection) between $\Lambda^2 V$ and $S^2 V$?

Comment: Once a basis is fixed, this comes down to injecting $\{(i,j)\in I\times I\colon i\le j\}$ into $\{(i,j)\in I\times I\colon i<j\}$. If we assume that $I$ has the order type of an infinite limit ordinal, then this can be done explicitly in a rather straightforward manner (consider the case $I=\mathbb{N}$).